# Show array data in html template by str_replace()

Tags: php, arrays, email, oop, replace

I am working on a PHP class where I replace variables with data to an HTML email template file. It works by replacing strings like "{{first_name}}" with data.

This way I can replace variables like first_name, last_name, email etc. with the right data of a customer. This works fine with single values, but now I have a problem.

In this e-mail I show the ordered products of the customer. This is an array products where each product has his own specifications (watch example array below).

**Question:**
Does anyone have an idea how I can implement the replacing of a {{variable}} with the loop of the products array?

**Products array example:**

```
$products = array(
    array( 
        'name'  => 'Product 1',
        'price' => 10.00,
        'qty'   => 1
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Product 2',
        'price' => 12.55,
        'qty'   => 1
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Product 3',
        'price' => 22.10,
        'qty'   => 3
    )
);
```

**My Class:**

```
class ConfirmationEmail {

    protected $_openingTag = '{{';
    protected $_closingTag = '}}';
    protected $_emailValues;
    protected $_template;

    /**
     * Email Template Parser Class.
     * @param string $templatePath HTML template string OR File path to a Email Template file.
     */ 
    public function __construct( $templatePath ) {
        $this->_setTemplate( $templatePath );
    }

    /**
     * Set Template File or String.
     * @param string $templatePath HTML template string OR File path to a Email Template file.
     */
    protected function _setTemplate( $templatePath ) {
        $this->_template = file_get_contents( $templatePath );
    }

    /**
     * Set Variable name and values one by one or at once with an array.
     * @param string $varName  Variable name that will be replaced in the Template.
     * @param string $varValue The value for a variable/key.
     */
    public function setVar( $varName, $varValue ) {

        if( ! empty( $varName ) && ! empty( $varValue ) ) {
            $this->_emailValues[$varName] = $varValue;  
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set Variable name and values with an array.
     * @param array $varArray Array of key=> values.
     */
    public function setVars( array $varArray ) {
        if( is_array( $varArray ) ) {
            foreach( $varArray as $key => $value ) {
                $this->_emailValues[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Parsed Email Template.
     * @return string HTML with any matching variables {{varName}} replaced with there values.
     */
    public function output() {

        $html = $this->_template;

        foreach( $this->_emailValues as $key => $value ) {
            if( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $html = str_replace( $this->_openingTag . $key . $this->_closingTag, $value, $html );
            }
        }   

        return $html;

    }
}
```

**In action:**

```
$template_path = 'path-to-template/email-templates/confirmation.php';
$emailHtml = new ConfirmationEmail( $template_path );

$emailHtml->setVars( array(
    'first_name'            => 'Jack',
    'last_name'         => 'Daniels',
    'street'                => 'First street',
    'number'                => '22',
    // Other data
));

// Outputs the HTML
echo $emailHtml->output();
```

**Ps.** I can show the HTML e-mail template to you if you want. This is an html structure of lots of tables with inline styles and {{variables}} on the place where the data needs to replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to display them. One option might be:

```
/**
 * Convert arrays to strings, ignore strings
 * @param mixed $var - variable to be instered
 */
 public function filterVars($var){
    if(is_array($var)){
        $str = "<table>";
        foreach($var as $k=>$v) $str .= "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td></tr>";
        $str .= "</table>";
        $var = $str;
    }
    return $var;
 }

/**
 * Set Variable name and values with an array.
 * @param array $varArray Array of key=> values.
 */
public function setVars( array $varArray ) {
    if( is_array( $varArray ) ) {
        foreach( $varArray as $key => $value ) {
            $val = $this->filterVars($value);
            $this->_emailValues[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is what I thought as well. But is this a clean way of doing it. Or is this a little bit of hacking?

Comment: The bottom line is, you have to covert the array to a string. Ideally you would do that before the array hits this function, that would be the clean way, but as far as tables go, that's really proably your best option. That;s what I do.

Comment: Okay, what if I choose the option to convert the array to string before. Do you mean to json encode it or something? Or do I need to create a whole other functionality?